# Export Texture Displaced Model from Maya with VRay

Tags: maya

I have a model made with Maya that uses VRay for texture displacement. How can I export an FBX mesh that has the texture displacement baked in? This is easy with the Arnold plugin as there is an option for baking. However, I see no such option in the VRay plugin.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with Chaos Group, it appears that they don't have a solution yet for this problem. They are aware of it and have it on their feature backlog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a texture deformer on a highly subdivided plane and plug in your displacement texture.

Comment: If the displacement texture had all info, then this could work. However, the displacement texture only has detailed deformation stored which must be applied to the high poly mesh.